# Triggering this script from php

Tags: php, bash

I have a script that works perfectly from the command line:

```
echo $1
cd /home/toomanycooks/whitewaterwriters.com
# In the right directory
git clone /home/toomanycooks/IMPS.git/ $1
echo "This directory"
cd $1/workingDirectory
echo $1/workingDirectory
./setup.sh $2
/usr/bin/python update.py
echo "$1, paused" >> /home/toomanycooks/whitewaterwriters.com/Driver/list.csv
```

However, using this php, it fails to trigger the python part:

```
<?php
$command = dirname(__FILE__).'/setupcamp.sh '.$_POST['slug']." ".$_POST['url']." ";
$temp = shell_exec($command );
echo "The camp with Slug: ". $slug. "and url ".$target_file." has been processed.";
echo nl2br($temp);
?>
```

This is what I get from "echo nl2br($temp);":

```
The camp with Slug: and url has been processed.testSE
This directory
testSE/workingDirectory
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Does `echo nl2br($temp);` output anything?

Comment: @noel - sensible question -  added content

Comment: The variables `$slug` and `$target_file` are not set.

Comment: ...and you should use [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) to properly quote/escape the characters of `$_POST['url']` (and `$_POST['slug']`) that have special meaning for the shell (`&`, f.e.).